# For what integers $n$, do we have $30n+11=6x^2+5y^2$ for some integers $x,y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratics, integers, quadratic-residues, sums-of-squares

I am trying to find all integers $m$ such that $m$ is relatively prime to 30, and $m=6x^2+5y^2$ for some integers $x,y$. Note that we must have: $y$ is odd, $(y,3)=1=(x,5)$. Using these conditions, I was able to show that $m=11$ or $29$ mod $30$. So I was first trying to handle the case $m=11$ mod 30. Note that $11=6\cdot1^2+5\cdot1^2$, but $41$ is not of the form $6x^2+5y^2$. So I was wondering, for which $n$  do we have $30n+11=6x^2+5y^2$? Also, for such $n$, can we obtain $x$ and $y$ satisfying $30n+11=6x^2+5y^2$?

Comment: There is usually no requirement that $x \neq y$ in these representations so your representation of $11$ is good.

Comment: mistake to use mod 30, correct is mod 120.  Legendre symbol $$  (-120|41)  = (3|41) = (41|3)  = (2|3) = -1. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values to look for are mod 120,  specifically $11, 29, 59, 101 \pmod{120}.$  There is a fairly clean theory about primes that are represented by a binary form. Since the class number $h(\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-30}]) = 4$  but there is one form in each genus, the primes $p = 5 x^2 + 6 y^2 $  are described precisely by congruences.

Other than the primes $2,3,5,$  the primes  such that $(-120|p) = 1$ are represented as such:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1. & 1,&31,&49,&79, & \pmod{120}& :: \; \; x^2 + 30 y^2 \\
2. & 17,&23,&47,&113, & \pmod{120}& :: \; \; 2x^2 + 15 y^2 \\
3. & 13,&37,&43,&67, & \pmod{120}& :: \; \; 3x^2 + 10 y^2 \\
6. & 11,&29,&59,&101, & \pmod{120}& :: \; \; 5x^2 + 6 y^2 \\
\end{array}
$$

Products of such primes are represented by one of the four forms, specified by Gauss composition. For example, $11 \cdot 29 = 319 = 17^2 + 30 \cdot 1^2 = 7^2 + 30 \cdot 3^2.$ Suppose we call the forms 1,2,3,6, where the last one is for $6 y^2 + 5 x^2.$  For a product of such "good" primes, write each one with a code 1,2,3,6. Then multiply,  table $1^2 = 2^2 = 3^2 = 6^2 = 1.$  Next $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ and $2 \cdot 6 = 3.$ Finally $3 \cdot 6 = 2.$   Well, here is a $2 \cdot 3 = 6.$ As in $17 \cdot 13 = 221 = 5 \cdot 5^2 + 6 \cdot 4^2 = 5 \cdot 1^2 + 6 \cdot 6^2 $

```
all values  mod 120
       0       5       6      11      14      20      21      24      26      29   
      30      35      36      44      45      50      51      54      56      59   
      60      66      69      74      75      80      84      86      90      96    
      99     101     104     110     114     116


prime to 120:   11,  29,  59, 101  

primes 

       5      11      29      59     101     131     149     179     251     269
     389     419     461     491     509     659     701     821     941     971
    1019    1061    1091    1109    1181    1229    1259    1301    1451    1499
    1571    1619    1709    1811    1901    1931    1949    1979    2069    2099
    2141    2309    2339    2381    2411    2459    2531    2549    2579    2621
    2699    2741    2789    2819    2861    2909    2939    3011    3221    3251
    3299    3371    3389    3461    3491    3539    3581    3659    3701    3779
    3821    3851    3989    4019    4091    4139    4211    4229    4259    4349
    4421    4451    4691    4931    5021    5051    5099    5171    5189    5261
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
 form  1     x^2 + 30 y^2
       0       1       4       9      16      25      30      31      34      36
      39      46      49      55      64      66      79      81      94     100
     111     120     121     124     129     130     136     144     145     151
     156     169     174     184     196     199     201     220     225     226
     241     255     256     264     270     271     274     279     286     289
     295     306     316     319     324     334     345     351     354     361
     370     376     391     400     409     414     430     439     441     444
     466     471     480     481     484     489     495     496     505     514
     516     520     526     529     544     559     561     576     580     594
     601     604     606     624     625     631     649     655     670     676

 form   2    2 x^2 + 15 y^2
       0       2       8      15      17      18      23      32      33      47
      50      60      62      65      68      72      78      87      92      98
     110     113     128     132     135     137     143     153     158     162
     167     177     185     188     200     207     215     222     233     240
     242     248     257     258     260     263     272     288     290     297
     302     303     312     335     338     348     353     368     375     377
     383     392     393     398     402     407     423     425     440     447
     450     452     465     473     482     503     510     512     527     528
     537     540     542     548     558     572     575     578     585     590
     593     612     617     632     638     647     648     663     668     690

 form   3   3 x^2 + 10 y^2
       0       3      10      12      13      22      27      37      40      43
      48      52      58      67      75      85      88      90      93     102
     108     115     117     118     138     147     148     157     160     163
     165     172     187     192     198     202     208     232     235     237
     243     250     253     262     268     277     282     283     298     300
     307     310     325     333     340     352     358     360     363     372
     373     387     390     397     403     408     432     435     442     453
     460     468     472     490     493     502     507     517     522     523
     538     547     550     552     565     588     592     597     598     603
     613     628     637     640     643     652     660     667     675     678

 form   6    5 x^2 + 6 y^2
       0       5       6      11      20      24      26      29      44      45
      51      54      59      69      74      80      86      96      99     101
     104     116     125     131     134     141     149     150     155     170
     176     179     180     186     195     204     216     221     230     234
     236     245     251     261     269     275     276     294     296     299
     314     320     326     330     339     341     344     374     384     389
     395     396     404     405     411     416     419     429     459     461
     464     470     474     486     491     500     501     506     509     524
     531     536     539     554     555     564     566     596     600     605
     611     614     620     621     629     645     650     659     666     680
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4442381/248217) I explore the factorization characteristics on class 4 domains when the class group is _specifically Klein-four_. Would this result be connected with that property of $\mathbb Z>\sqrt{-30}]$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi  Hi. The unusually clean setup is due to having one class per genus, for positive forms this is Euler's Idoneal Numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idoneal_number   I will see if I can come up with one class per genus but eight genera, this might require indefinite forms. Take a few minute at least.  Quicker than expected, idoneal number 105,  class number eight, all forms square to the identity,      420:  < 1, 0, 105>     420:  < 2, 2, 53>     420:  < 3, 0, 35>     420:  < 5, 0, 21>     420:  < 6, 6, 19>     420:  < 7, 0, 15>     420:  < 10, 10, 13>     420:  < 11, 8, 11>

Comment: Alright, 16 genera, one class per genus, Discriminant      -5460     h :   16     Squares :    1     cubes :   16     Fourths :    1
    5460:  < 1, 0, 1365>    5460:  < 2, 2, 683>    5460:  < 3, 0, 455>    5460:  < 5, 0, 273>    5460:  < 6, 6, 229>    5460:  < 7, 0, 195>    5460:  < 10, 10, 139>    5460:  < 13, 0, 105>    5460:  < 14, 14, 101>    5460:  < 15, 0, 91>    5460:  < 21, 0, 65>    5460:  < 26, 26, 59>    5460:  < 30, 30, 53>    5460:  < 35, 0, 39>    5460:  < 37, 4, 37>    5460:  < 42, 42, 43>

Comment: [OEIS A000926](https://oeis.org/A000926) reports that the class group for the relevant discriminants is indeed $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$, which is the Klein four-group for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-30}] (n=2)$.

Comment: I made your class number rendering more precise (giving the ring, not just the discriminant which may apply to other rings). Feel free to roll back if you want.

Answer (score 0):

if n>0, then left hand side is positive, and 30n+11 chooses an ellipse from right-hand side which contains an ellipse for each value in $\{ (x,y) | f(n,x,y)=g(n,x,y), (n,x,y) \in (Z,Z,Z) \}$ where $f(n,x,y)=30n+1$ and $g(n,x,y)=6x²+5y²$. After you realize that it's just an ellipse for positive values of the left hand side, then the next step is to realize that the integers are a grid that needs to intersect the ellipse.